# jQuery selector needed for first matched element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<p class="expand">Click to expand</p>
<div class="expand-box">
   <p>Some content here</p>
</div>
```

with this jquery:

```
$('.expander-box').hide();
$('.expand').toggle(function() {
   $(this).next('.expander-box').slideDown();
}, function() {
   $(this).next('.expander-box').slideUp();
});
```

My question is this: This code works fine, but if the expander-box is not directly after the p.expand tag then it wont work. Is there a better selector to use rather than next() so that when clicked it will start from the clicked element and go down the page until it finds an expander-box and then performs the animation on that first matched element?$this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
$('.expander-box').hide();
$('.expand').toggle(function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.expander-box:first').slideDown();
}, function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.expander-box:first').slideUp();
});
```

Or much simpler with [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), like this:

```
$('.expander-box').hide();
$('.expand').click(function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.expander-box:first').slideToggle();
});
```

Note that both of these will find the next `.expander-box` **that's a sibling**, if it's some more complex structure you're better off knowing the structure and using [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to navigate to the element starting with `this`, similar to how you're doing it with just siblings now.

---

Of course, there are several variations available like most cases:

```
$(this).nextAll('.expander-box:first').slideToggle();
$(this).nextAll('.expander-box').first().slideToggle();
$(this).nextAll('.expander-box').eq(0).slideToggle();
//etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the jQuery constructor with two arguments "roots" the query at the second argument:

$('.expander-box', this) returns all the '.expander-box' that are *children* of *this*.
So, if you make your HTML look like this:

```
<p class="expand">Click to expand
<div class="expand-box">
   <p>Some content here</p>
</div>
</p>
```

The above query will do what you want it to do.